# How to generate every possible string combination of 4 letters and store in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

**In C** I need to make an array which contains every possible 5 letter string combination of the letters "A", "C", "G", "T". That is, 
AAAAA,
AAAAG,
AAAAC,
etc.
And I need these stored in an array. I'm aware there are 1024 possible combinations, and therefore the array would be allocated with that in mind.
I think the memory allocation would look something like this:

```
char* combinations[] = calloc(1024, 5*sizeof(char));
```

Not sure about how to fill such an array with all possible combinations.

Comment: Before we get started with the algorithm I will point out that if your string is meant to contain five characters you need the string to be at least *6* characters long to hold the null terminator

Comment: A recursive solution is perhaps preferable to 5 nested loops.

Comment: And you think that we enjoy writing code for others that have not tried.

Comment: @GovindParmar yep, thanks I forgot that.

Comment: It seems you are in fact in need of understanding some basics. So, you want to learn how an array of pointers to characters work, and how to access the individual letters. So, your goal is that this code will correctly print out what you have stored in the array before: `for (size_t i=0; i<1024; ++i) { printf("%s\n", combinations[i]; }`

Comment: What about `char a[1024][5 + 1];`?

Comment: @BodoThiesen yes, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// type to encapsulate our 5 character long string
typedef char combination[5];

combination* getCombinations()
{
  char letters[] = {'A','C','G','T'};
  combination * combinations = (combination *)calloc(1024, sizeof(combination));
  unsigned i;
  unsigned int j;

  for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
  {
    /*combinations[i] = &strings[i * 5];*/
    for ( j = 5; j--;){
      combinations[i][(4 - j)] = letters[(i >> (j * 2)) % 4]; // 
    }
  }

  return combinations;
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  combination * combinations = getCombinations();
  for ( i = 0; i < 1024; i++){
    printf("%.*s\n", 5, combinations[i]);
  }

  free(combinations);
}
```

The important line is the inner loop:

```
combinations[i][4 - j] = letters[(i >> (j * 2)) % 4];
```

The purpose of this line is to turn an index (0-1023) into a combination by simply counting up.

Let's break this down:

- `letters[... % 4]` returns a letter based on whatever (`...`) is. the `% 4` part just makes indexing at `1`, `5`, `9`, ... all return `'C'`
- `(i >> (j * 2))` this basically allows us to select in base `4` (the number of possible letters)
- `combinations[i][4 - j]` sets the value to the `j`th letter (counting from the right) of the `i`th word in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(char** out, int n, char* p)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        memcpy(*out, p - 5, 5);
        *out += 5;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        *p = "ACGT"[i];
        f(out, n - 1, p + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
  char* combinations = calloc(1024, 5);
  char* comb = combinations;
  char buf[5];
  f(&comb, 5, buf);

  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
    printf("%.5s\n", combinations + i * 5);
}
```